# linking error when using OpenCv code in C++ builder 10.3

Tags: opencv, cmake, linker-errors, c++builder, rad-studio

I already created the borland makefiles needed to use opencv in embarcadero c++ builder using the steps shown [here](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Using_CMake_with_C%2B%2B_Builder) and the Cmake command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=bcc32x.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=bcc32x.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Wno-c++11-narrowing" -G"Borland Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_OPENEXR=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_world=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_WEBP=OFF -DWITH_OPENCL=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -DWITH_TIFF=OFF -DBUILD_TIFF=OFF -G Ninja C:/openCV/opencv-XE7
```

After the ninja was finished I added the include of the openCv folder to the tools->options->language->C++ options->Paths and Directories->system include path for the clang compiler. After that I added the lib file of the folder where CMake put it into the library path. I also added the lib file to project->options->building-C++ compiler->Directories and conditionals->include file search path.
After I finished I wanted to test if it would work. First I wanted to test if no errors would occur after using the header:

`#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`

This created no errors but when I used a simple line of code like:

`cv::Mat frame`

I get the following error:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'cv::Mat::deallocate()' referenced from C:\USERS\XANDERV\DOCUMENTS\GIT\APPLICATION SOFTWARE\OPENCVTEST\WIN32\DEBUG\MAIN.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'cv::fastFree(void *)' referenced from C:\USERS\XANDERV\DOCUMENTS\GIT\APPLICATION SOFTWARE\OPENCVTEST\WIN32\DEBUG\MAIN.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
```

I thought I had already linked the libraries and added those libraries to the project. Did I add the libraries to the wrong place or did something happen with the CMake command I used or is it something else.