# linking error cmake OpenCV for rad studio 10.3 when using make install

Tags: opencv, cmake, linker-errors, c++builder, rad-studio

I am trying to use opencv code in embarcadero C++ builder 10.3 for a project. To do that I use the RAD studio command prompt and CMake. First I used ninja and CMake like explained [here](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Using_CMake_with_C%2B%2B_Builder). The CMake command I used for that is:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=bcc32x.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=bcc32x.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Wno-c++11-narrowing" -G"Borland Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_OPENEXR=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_world=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_WEBP=OFF -DWITH_OPENCL=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -DWITH_TIFF=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_objdetect=OFF -DBUILD_TIFF=OFF -G Ninja C:/openCV/opencv-XE7
```

I succeeded in creating a lib file where libraries are created but when trying to use it in C++ builder I get the following [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76423476/linking-error-when-using-opencv-code-in-c-builder-10-3). So I want to try to create the lib files without using the ninja command and instead use the make or make install command so I removed the *-G Ninja* from the CMake command and used the make command after generating. But that created the following error:

```
[ 29%] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\opencv_core300d.dll
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Embarcadero Technologies Inc. bcc32x version 5.0.2 (36752.0cce431.9f79754) (based on LLVM 5.0.2)
Target: i686-pc-windows-omf
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin
bcc32x.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nobuiltininc' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
 "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\20.0\\bin\\ilink32.exe\"" "@\"C:\\Users\\xanderv\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\....binopencv_core300d-3a9a9c.cfg\""
Turbo Incremental Link 6.90 Copyright (c) 1997-2017 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Fatal: Unable to open file '....LIBOPENCV_HAL300D.LIB'
bcc32x.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 2 (use -Xdriver -v to see invocation)
** error 2 ** deleting bin\opencv_core300d.dll
** error 1 ** deleting modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir\all
** error 1 ** deleting all
```

I get this error every time I use make or make install and have no idea why that error is created. Is there something wrong with my CMake command or did I install something wrong.

The specifications are:
CMake 3.19.4 
OpenCV [this site](https://github.com/boaz001/opencv/tree/XE7)
C++ builder 10.3